# Using alias name inside Case Function mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I use alias name inside Case Function:

```
SELECT SUM(rupees) as sumvalue, 
CASE
    WHEN sumvalue > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
    WHEN sumvalue = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
    ELSE "The quantity is something else"
END
from house_details;
```

Comment: Assign it to a variable and use that variable in the `CASE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use alias at same level of query you need to repeat your expression

```
SELECT SUM(rupees) as sumvalue, 
CASE
    WHEN SUM(rupees) > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
    WHEN SUM(rupees) = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
    ELSE "The quantity is something else"
END
from house_details;
```

custom aliases can be accessed in outer query like

```
SELECT sumvalue,
    CASE
        WHEN sumvalue > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
        WHEN sumvalue = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
        ELSE "The quantity is something else"
    END
FROM(
    SELECT SUM(rupees) as sumvalue from house_details;
) t
```

Comment: Hello @Khalid Junaid i need to change the result in this format i have mentioned in the link https://i.imgur.com/nbHKN8Y.png and my tables schema is in this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d8c4/1

Comment: @KannanK Can you please ask a new question as this change will make this answer invalid, Also do include your description(what you need), tried query and fiddle link so that SO users can get correct understanding.

Comment: @Khalid Junaid I have asked a new question please check the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937513/getting-values-from-three-tables-using-join-and-group-by

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(rupees) as sumvalue, 
(CASE
    WHEN sumvalue > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
    WHEN sumvalue = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
    ELSE "The quantity is something else"
END ) as MyValue
from house_details;
```

**Note: Just use some parenthesis and It will work Fine.**

Use the CASE Function inside the Parenthesis i.e  (CASE When value > 30 Then "Value is greater than 30"
When value = 30 Then "Value is 30") **as MyValue**